# Single channel CL9 vs dual channel CL11

Tags: memory, latency, ddr3

I have to upgrade the DDR3 RAM of an old PC.  At the same price, do I get the best performance with a single channel cl9 or a dual channel cl11? Both 1600MHz

Comment: The performance delta between those two modules will be impossible to measure in real world usage cases.

Comment: I know but since the price is exactly the same which theoretically offers the best performance even if by a little?

Comment: Dual channel gives a real measurable benefit in that it actually doubles your RAM bandwidth. CL9 vs CL11 only gives you a benefit at the absolute edge of performance. Go for dual channel over fractionally faster RAM.

Comment: @Franz - Any performance difference with DDR3 memory that similar can’t be measured in real world applications

Comment: @Ramhound I get it, you already said that.  that's not what i asked for.  thanks anyway.

Comment: @Franz - Don’t know how else to explain it, there will no performance differences, between those two speeds, a.25 ns won’t make any difference at all. If you want a hardware recommendation between the two modules, post your question on the hardware recommendation stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Some games benefit from dual channel while for others there will be
no benefit, so the latency may look like it's more important.

However, the difference between CL9 and CL11 is very minimal.

From the article
[The Difference Between RAM Speed and CAS Latency](https://www.crucial.com/articles/about-memory/difference-between-speed-and-latency):

> Latency is often misunderstood because on product flyers and spec
> comparisons, it's noted in CAS Latency (CL), which is only half of the
> latency equation. Because CL ratings indicate only the total number of
> clock cycles, they don't have anything to do with the duration of each
> clock cycle, and thus, they shouldn't be extrapolated as the sole
> indicator of latency performance.
>
> By looking at a module's latency in terms of nanoseconds, you can best
> judge if one module is, in fact, more responsive than another. To
> calculate a module's latency, multiply clock cycle duration by the
> total number of clock cycles. These numbers will be noted in official
> engineering documentation on a module's data sheet. Here's what these
> calculations look like.

| Technology | Module Speed (MT/s) | Clock Cycle Time(ns) | CAS Latency | Latency (ns) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DDR3 | 1333 | 1.50 | 9 | **13.50** |
| DDR3 | 1600 | 1.25 | 11 | **13.75** |

Since the CL difference is minimal, while dual channel can be important,
I would opt for dual channel.